# Amazon S3 iOS SDK background upload with progress block

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on an app that depends on AWS for file uploads and downloads. In the case of uploads, when I upload video files using AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest, I can show progress bar using progress block, but when I press home button and app enters background, the upload pauses (probably because it uses NSURLConnection). Only if the app is running in foreground will upload take place.

This is the code for uploading files using AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest.

```
AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];

AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];

uploadRequest.bucket = bucketName;
uploadRequest.key = appropriateKey;

uploadRequest.body = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

uploadRequest.contentType = contentType;

uploadRequest.uploadProgress = progressBlock;


[[transferManager upload:uploadRequest] continueWithExecutor:[AWSExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
    if (task.error)
    {
        if ([task.error.domain isEqualToString:AWSS3TransferManagerErrorDomain])
        {
            switch (task.error.code)
            {
                case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorCancelled:
                case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorPaused:
                    break;

                default:
                    failBlock(task.error.code, task.error.localizedDescription);
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            failBlock(task.error.code, task.error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }
    if (task.result)
    {
        AWSS3TransferManagerUploadOutput *uploadOutput = task.result;
        successBlock(uploadOutput);
    }
    return nil;
}];
```

This works, except for transfer in background.

So, I went ahead and used the AWS's pre-signed URLs. The following is the code for the same.

```
AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest *getPreSignedURLRequest = [AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest new];
getPreSignedURLRequest.bucket = bucketName;

getPreSignedURLRequest.key = appropriateKey;
getPreSignedURLRequest.HTTPMethod = AWSHTTPMethodPUT;
getPreSignedURLRequest.expires = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3600];


//Important: set contentType for a PUT request.
NSString *fileContentTypeStr = contentType;
getPreSignedURLRequest.contentType = fileContentTypeStr;
[[[AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder defaultS3PreSignedURLBuilder] getPreSignedURL:getPreSignedURLRequest]
 continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {

     if (task.error) {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@",task.error);
     } else {

         NSURL *presignedURL = task.result;
         NSLog(@"upload presignedURL is: \n%@", presignedURL);

         NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:presignedURL];
         request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;
         [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
         [request setValue:fileContentTypeStr forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


         NSURLSession *session;
         NSURL *uploadFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
         NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:uploadFileUrl];
         //uploadTask is an instance of NSURLSessionDownloadTask.
         //session is an instance of NSURLSession.
         [uploadTask resume];

     }

     return nil;
 }];
```

This solves the problem of uploading in the background. But it does not have a progress block and because of that I cannot track progress.

I have to be able to track progress and upload from background. Is this possible? Or is there any workaround?

Comment: Have you found a way to pre-sign, upload and track progress at the same time?

Comment: @Eusthace Check my answer.. I did. They provide TransferUtility. It is still in beta, but works as per requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I did a lot of digging around and found an answer for this. It may be helpful for someone.

The AWSS3TransferManager has progress block to track progress but no support for background transfer. And AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest has support for background transfer but no way to track progress.

They have another service via which you can track progress and upload/download in the background. Using AWSS3TransferUtility, you can do both these things. Do note that this is still in beta.

Refer the docs for more info - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transferutility.html

I had a lot of trouble with this(partly due to my ignorance). I hope this is useful for anyone with similar problems.

Comment: Yup had the same issue. Spent many hours implementing TransferManager only to figure out it was useless for my case. Whats even more annoying is that while TransferManager makes it very easy to integrate with a tableview and multiple uploads. The TransferUtility does not. AWS SDK has always been pretty unintuitive in my opinion.

Comment: I am using AWSS3TransferUtility for uploading files. Uploading is working in background but the uploading progress gets zero with network drops. It should get resume with network reachability in my case. Is this possible?

Comment: @Ada I don't think transfer utility supports parallel uploads, and if you are not supporting parallel uploads, why don't you make a single object of AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask and call resume on it. If that doesn't work, then its probably not possible to resume it on network drops. Refer http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transferutility.html

Comment: @MeharoofNajeeb I am supporting parallel uploads. I have also tried resume on single AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask after network comes back but It's not working. Uploads are getting restart. Can you please confirm me that this is not possible or is there a way to do this.

Comment: @Ada Its not possible to support resume on network drop using AWSS3TransferUtility as of now. I just went through their docs again just now. If you want to support this, why don't you try multipart upload feature?

Comment: @MeharoofNajeeb I have also tried AWSS3TransferManager that supports multipart upload but it doesn't support uploading in background. I need both the features. Is this possible?

Comment: @Skywalker can you send me some of your sorce code to uplaod a large video in 5mb chuncks to AWS s3 bucket using Pre signed URL. I am looking for NSURLsession code specifically.

Comment: @RahulVyas Check this.. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/how-to-ios-s3-presigned-urls.html

Comment: @Skywalker I am using transfferManager to upload large video and it handles uploading in chucnks. but when I pause and resume the progress bar updated to 100% but stuck after that finalizing in last part.

Also the sdk has now updated Transffer utility and added some new features.

Comment: @RahulVyas So you want to use transfer utility now because transfer manager pause-resume has issues? Or were you able to implement it already? What's your question? If it is a different question than this, then please ask a new question with more details and tag here. I'll take a look and see if I can fix

Comment: I have already implemented transfer manager but it stuck when pause and resume. Do you have any idea about this ?

Comment: @RahulVyas No. Pause and resume used to work for me if I remember correctly. Its been so long since that and I don't have the means to test it out again. Only going to background had issues.

Comment: @Skywalker do you have any idea about this? I'm uploading a video using TransferUtility but my rest API call fails when the app is in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this is fundamentally not supported using core iOS background upload capabilities.

By design, the NSURLSession background upload will take 100s of parallel chunks and only return success/fail as an atomic response generally. The actual progress is opaque to the app.

You can't really get around this, the more you serialise, the more you trigger "next part" uploads which will quickly incur the wrath of the rate limiting side of that.

Background upload is specifically designed to be minimal touch to save battery and 3G data usage. It's not designed for anything interactive.

I wonder, given the need to use background upload, presumably for large assets, what is the actual need to show the user progress that may be very slow? Isn't success/fail enough?

Maybe to solve this you could run the uploads in the foreground if absolutely necessary, then you will have the feedback, if the user gets sick of waiting or the phone sleeps, then in the app teardown call-back, switch to resuming on a background task as the user is no longer interested in watching the progress bar?