# AWS S3 TransferManger vs. TransferUtility

Tags: amazon-s3, swift3, aws-sdk, awss3transfermanager, awss3transferutility

Not too long ago I stumbled upon AWS's S3 iOS SDK and I use it faithfully in my projects.

Recently a project is requiring me to implement a new feature that i've never done before, uploading media to S3 and continuing the upload even if the app gets moved to the background.

After some research, it was recommended to utilize AWS S3 Transfer Utility. I believe this is the correct approach after looking at the documentation, however, I've been using TransferManager for a while now, and I don't quite understand the differences between the 2 OUTSIDE of the ability to continue a data transfer when the app is in the background.

My Question: What are the functional differences between **TransferManger** and **TransferUtility**?

Answer (score 1):

The main idea is that S3 TransferManager for iOS **does not support background transfer**. And main feature of S3 Transfer Utility for iOS is the ability to continue transferring data in the background (as you read in documentation, I guess).

Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34875813/5928311) is more about your question